# The logo on the Stack Overflow Developer Survey page is old

Tags: bug, logo, survey, survey-2015

On the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey page](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015) is the old logo:

[image]

[image]

This affects both the coloured one at the top, and the sidebar greyscale one.

Comment: I think it makes more sense leaving it as-is, because that *was* the logo when those results were published. The [previous](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) [surveys](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) also have old logos in their infographics.

Comment: @animuson Sure, but soon that page will be used for the 2016 results, no?

Comment: I don't believe so. There should be a new page for the 2016 results. Otherwise we'd lose all the 2015 results, for people who are interested in seeing the past ones (that's why the year is explicitly in the URL).

Comment: @animuson You click the tabs for each year's data: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech

Comment: The entire page itself is basically a replacement for the blog for the 2015 results. Once the 2016 results are published, almost none of the information on that entire page will be accurate anymore, because presumably the data will have changed since last year. The tabs are just for reference to previous years for those few pieces of information, compared to 2015. I'm sure the 2016 results will have similar tabs, but the 2016 results themselves will be published on a completely different page. The page is being redesigned and rewritten already.

Comment: @animuson I see, okay.